# How to use applicaiton-only oauth in twitter?

Tags: android, twitter, oauth-2.0

Can anyone show me how to use the application-only oauth in twitter? I have to implement it in my app but i cant find ANY tutorials on net for the new api 1.1. An example would be much better...

Answer (score 1):

Hi the following code include how to use application-only OAuth and get user_timeline.

1. download this library http://loopj.com/android-async-http/
2. use this code

   ```
   /*
    * -url user_timeline 
    * -client and asyncHttpResponseHandler is used to get timeline
    */
   String url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=<NAME>";
   AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
   AsyncHttpResponseHandler asyncHttpResponseHandler = new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

     public void onSuccess(String response) {
        /*--------- DidReceiveData ---------*/
        Log.e("", "JSON FILE "+" response " + response);
     };
   };

   /*
    * OAuth Starts Here
    */
   RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
   requestParams.put("grant_type", "client_credentials");
   AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
   httpClient.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((CONSUMER_KEY + ":" + CONSUMER_SECRET).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
   httpClient.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
   httpClient.post("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token", requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

           public void onSuccess(String responce) {

               try {
                   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(
                           responce);
                   Log.e("", "token_type " + jsonObject.getString("token_type") + " access_token " + jsonObject.getString("access_token"));
                   client.addHeader("Authorization", jsonObject.getString("token_type") + " " + jsonObject.getString("access_token"));
                   client.get(url, asyncHttpResponseHandler);
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           };

           public void onFailure(Throwable error, String response) {
               Log.e("", "error " + error.toString() + " response " + response);

           };

       });
   ```